# LibGDX Music louder after switching screens

Tags: java, audio, libgdx

I've encountered something strange in my LibGDX project. I'm currently using a `Music` instance to play my ambient music, which itself is a copy of another external `static Music` instance. My problem comes when I swap screens and then swap back to the previous screen - the audio playback becomes noticeably higher in volume even though the music.getVolume() returns the same value. I've already made sure that I stop the music from playing and I dispose of the music object, so I don't think it's because more than one music instance is overlapping.

Code:

```
//In my assets class
public static final Music RAIN_AMBIENT_MUSIC = Gdx.audio.newMusic(Gdx.files.internal("music/ambient/rain.mp3"));

//In my screen's show() method
background_music_1 = Assets.RAIN_AMBIENT_MUSIC;
background_music_1.setLooping(true);
background_music_1.play();
background_music_1.setVolume(0.5f);

//In my screen's hide() method
background_music_1.stop();
dispose();

//In my screen's dispose method
background_music_1.dispose();
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried using AssetManager instead of just loading music in a static storage?

Comment: @Kush I switched all of my loading to an AssetManager instead, but the problem still persists, even if I manually change the volume when I change screens.